# NSLocalizedString - Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS with String.localizedStringWithFormat

Tags: ios, swift, string, nslocalizedstring

I tried to make a notification with some localized variables. In the simulator, everything works without an error - even the notification shows up as it should, but if I test it on an iPhone, the app crashes.

```
    func getContent(fromName: String, andDue: String, andAmount: Double) -> UNMutableNotificationContent {
        let currency = self.appDelegate.settings.getShortCurrency() // standard währung aus dem System holen
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()


        content.subtitle = NSLocalizedString("REMINDERTITLE", comment: "Reminder: some payments are overdue...")


    // Error in this line:
    content.body = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("REMINDERTEXT", comment: "Hey, %@'s payment from %@ %@ is overdue since %@! Do you want to send him a reminder message?"), fromName, andAmount, currency, andDue)

        content.badge = 1
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "droppingCoin.wav")

        return content
    }
```

The error is:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4084900000000000)

in this line:

```
content.body = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("REMINDERTEXT", comment: "Hey, %@'s payment from %@ %@ is overdue since %@! Do you want to send him a reminder message?"), fromName, andAmount, currency, andDue)
```

The comment text is the actual localized text value defined in the .strings file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier for andAmount. andAmount is a double and not an object, so use %f instead of %@.

Comment: for real! damn, how could I have missed that? BIG Thanks!